# Create a custom typings file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I just created a published `npm` package for the first time, called "Foo".  I am trying to consume it in a typescript project, but none of the tutorials about how to declare modules with custom typings, are clear to me.  Here are the key parts of the npm package:

`news.ts`

```
import { tdsRequest } from "../common/request";

function articles(uri) {
  return tdsRequest({ method: "GET" }, uri).then(returnData => console.log(returnData, "return data"));
}

export {
  articles,
};
```

`main.ts` (main export)

```
import * as news from "./services/news";

export default {
  news
};
```

in the typescript project that's consuming the `npm` package:
`import { news } from "Foo";`

and in the typings file ( `Foo.d.ts` ) I did:

```
declare module "Foo" {
    export {
        news: Object,
    };
}
```

I get the following errors: `cannot find module news` and `Cannot export 'Object'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing default and named exports.

You can do **default export style** -

main.ts:

```
import * as news from "./services/news";

export default {
  news
};
```

ts project import:

```
 import foo from "Foo";
 const {news} = foo;
```

foo.d.ts:

```
declare module "Foo" {
    export default {
        news: Object,
    };
}
```

Or you can do **named exports**:

main.ts:

```
import * as news from "./services/news";

export {
  news
};
```

ts project import:

```
 import {news} from "Foo";
```

foo.d.ts:

```
declare module "Foo" {
    export const news: Object;
}
```

---

But more importantly, you should add `declaration: true` to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` in your npm library.

This will generate the `d.ts` file for you and will save you lots of work. Then, you need to add in `package.json` a filed called `types` that will point to the `main.d.ts` file that will be generated for you. This will allow any project using your library + typescript to use the generated types automatically.